# Hibernate hsql queries have no effect when called from servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, hsqldb

I am having problems using my DAO (Data Access Object) classes on my servlets.

Everything works fine in a simple main method when not deployed on the server, but using the same classes in my servlets doGet methods seems to have no effect on database. I still get the query messages on console, for example:

```
Hibernate: select something_id.something from something
```

but nothing returns...

Im using a memory database (`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1`) and EntityManager to insert and retrieve from it (mostly `createQuery()`) in my DAO classes methods.

Im testing on eclipse localhost server preview. Tried Tomcat and Glassfish also, but they didnt seem to change anything so I returned to the default.

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong or what might be the issue?

I cant provide any specific code right now, because it is in my work computer, but i will in approximately 12 hours if its needed to help solve this issue.

**EDIT**

Solved my problem. I foolishly executed my database schema creation file with every get request and thats why the queries didnt seem to work :). I'll be more thorough next time!

Comment: What is something_id.something means? is it property of something class? Provide example persistence class.

Comment: Its just a sample query, it prints the same things to the console when im accessing from main method.

Comment: I would guess the db is empty, or at least nothing matches your query.  Have you verified that you are connecting to the right db and that there are records in it?

Comment: It looks like its empty, but before im taking data out im inserting some rows into it without any errors or exceptions.

Comment: My guess is you are suppressing exception some where.

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/mkalmo/exjpa/src/c37fd12029e3f348411af188d70cdbaedc767d84?at=master) is roughly what my code looks like. Extracted the methods from main to a dao object.

Comment: Are you sure that when you are trying to insert, it is working. If you pretty sure that only retrieving is giving an error then just insert for once using your code(comment the retrieving part), and check if data is getting inserted in the DB.